# Error when I try to install Cloud Foundry cli on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, installation

I am trying to install the Cloud Foundry CLI from: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli

However, after I download the ZIP file, unzip it, and click on the installation .pkg (In the installers folder, under osx), I get this error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.installer.pagecontroller error -1.)"

I have Mac OSX 10.7.4, and this is a brand new laptop. A coworker of mine, with the same OSX, downloaded and installed it with no problem.

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That error may depend on some files which needs to be moved, or it could be a file which needs to be converted into a mountable Disk Image file.

or as suggested on https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli
If you are on OS X, you can also install the CLI with homebrew--run  `brew install cloudfoundry-cli`

if thats not the problem then you should try to download it from Safari(if you aren't using it) or

"open the .mpkg file with Disk Utility and create an uncompressed read/write .dmg. Mount the dmg and run the .mpkg and all should be fine." (as quoted by a user that had a solution to not being able to run the downloader, but it might work with this one too.)

Good luck!

Source:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2628710?start=0&tstart=0
https://discussions.apple.com/message/22613031#22613031